# how do i determine which class an interface contains

Tags: c#, class, interface, xna

i have a set of classes that belong to an interface;

```
public  class Platform : IGraphic
{
}

public class Decal : IGraphic
{
}

public class Character : IGraphic
{
}

public interface IGraphic
{
}
```

If i set an IGraphic value to point to say Decal like so;

```
IGraphic graphic = new Decal();
```

How can i, at some later point,  determine which Class the Interface has been set to?

Comment: Why do you want to know which class? If you need to know, then you have probably designed your program incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine the implementation of an interface by using:

```
graphic.GetType()
```

Answer (score 1):

First, classes do not belong to an interface, they can implement it.
Now, after we have defined it you can see that implementing the interface enables you to know that such methods are implemented in each class that implements the interface.
So your question is kind of backwards, you can implement the method differently for each class so you won't have to know what is the type of your object.

If you insist knowing the type you can use reflection. 
I advice you using reflection as less as you can.
If you wan't to describe the purpose of your program maybe we can help you avoiding reflection (usually- a better architecture)

Comment: ok i have a list of objects. they are platforms, decals and characters (for a platform game). each one contains some common information; icon, name. Some will contain unique information; a platform will contain images for the left, middle and right side of the platform while a decal will only contain a single image. So i am using an interface so i can hold these different objects within a single list.

Comment: But why do you need to know which list element is of which concrete class? This sounds very much like a very common design error.

Comment: it probably is. i have only just started learning. more information; i am writing a level editor for a game. the various objects for the game are loaded from a file (platforms, decals, characters). each object has an icon. in order to display the icons in groups i need to know what type they are.

Comment: i would greatly appreciate any advice you could give me on implementing something to handle this situation properly. thanks

Comment: Ok, If the groups have a purpose like so, you could add classes for each group. and even derive from those. Otherwise you can have an enum   property for each map object ,although  the first solution is better.

Comment: sorry for my ignorance. i am very new to this. i have classes for the groups now. "i'm not sure what you mean by derive from those". do you mean inheritance? would it be possible to see a small code example?

Answer (score 0):

Use `graphic.GetType()`.

This will get the `Type` of the instance.

Note that this works for every kind of object, not just for interfaces.

You could conceivably also use

```
if (graphic is Platform)
```

or

```
if (graphic is Decal)
```

etc.